# Question about definite integral with uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Here is the related problem:

> Let $\{f_{n}:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}\}$ be a sequence of functions defined by $$f_{n}(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\left\{1+(x-y)^{n}\cdot\sin^{n}(xy)\right\}\,dy$$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\{f_{n}\}$ converges uniformly to some function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ on $[0,1]$.

My first attempt was as follows:

> Since $f_{n}(0)=0$ and $f_{n}'(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$ by the **F.T.C.** for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f_{n}'(x)$ converges uniformly to the constant $1$ on $[0,1]$.
>
> Hence, $\{f_{n}\}$ converges uniformly to the function $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ by the well-known theorem(for differentiablility with uniform convergence).

But, I'm not sure whether it could apply the F.T.C. to $f_{n}$'s, because the integrand have mixed variables $x$ and $y$.

(Here, "**F.T.C.**" means the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)

Can anyone criticize my attempt if it is a completely wrong argument, or notice me if there is a different version of the fundamental theorem of calculus for this problem. Thank you!

Comment: You're not asked to compute the limit, wouldn't it be simpler showing somehow Cauchy's criterion instead?

Comment: Your argument that $f'_n(x)=1$ is flawed. Note that $x$ also shows up in the integrand, and there should be an additional term according to the Leibniz rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:** $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$, where $f(x)=x$.

For each $x\in [0,1]$, we have 
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left|\int_0^x[1+(x-y)^n\sin^n(xy)]\,dy-\int_0^xdy\right|\\\le\int_0^x|x-y|^n|\sin(xy)|^ndy\\\le\int_0^x|\sin(xy)|^ndy$$
since for each $x,y\in[0,1]$ we must have $|x-y|\le 1$. Now, for each $x,y\in [0,1]$, it is clear that $xy\in [0,1]$, and so $\sin(xy)\in [0,\sin 1]$. Thus, 
$$\int_0^x|\sin(xy)|^ndy\le x(\sin 1)^n\le(\sin 1)^n.$$
Since $1\in (0,\pi/2)$, $\sin 1\in (0,1)$. So for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $(\sin 1)^n<\epsilon$. ...